# How is a Func<T> implicitly converted to Expression<Func<T>>?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression, linq-expressions

I don't understand what is happening here:

Both of these lines compile:

```
 Func<object> func = () => new object();

 Expression<Func<object>> expression = ()=>new object();
```

But this doesn't:

```
 expression = func;
```

There isn't an implicit operator on `LambdaExpression` or `Expression<TDelegate>` that converts a delegate to the expression, so something else must be happening to make the assignment work.  What is it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not an implicit conversion in the usual sense - it's a compiler trick. The compiler detects which one is expected from the context, and then compiles it either as a delegate (a hidden method on your class) or as an expression (a chunk of code that constructs the expression by calling the methods on `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`).

This is the reason you can't directly assign a lambda expression to a variable of type `object` or `var`, among other things, because the compiler has to be able to know whether you mean a delegate or an expression.

Comment: More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic20).

Comment: Re the last - plus it would need to decide *what delegate type* (or expression-of-delegate-type) to use; there is nothing special about `Func<...>` etc.