# Repository Using Where

Tags: c#, lambda, repository, linq-expressions

I am beginner in repository design pattern.So i want to learn how to use "where" in repository.

I have repository code below,

**Model**

```
public T First(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{
return DbSet.First(where);
}
```

I want to use where clause below however , i do not know what parameter i must give in order to "where" clause ?

**Controller:**

```
var r = new Repository<Department>(new MyDbEntities());

r.First(..........) // it says (Expression<FuncDepartment,bool>>where):Department
```

I want to match department name in my database departmane name field.

What to add in stead of "........." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass `Func<Department, bool>` - it will be [converted to expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862266/how-is-a-funct-implicitly-converted-to-expressionfunct):

```
r.First(d => d.Name == "department name")
```