# Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> and Sql IN

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to use expression trees to make filters with entity framework.

So this is my types

```
public class Type1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Type2
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my specification

```
public Expression<Func<Entities.Type1, bool>> MyExpression(Type2 filter)
{
    //something like where name in (name[0], name[1], ... name[n])
}
```

I need transform this in something like Sql where in.

How can I do it, and what's the best form?

How can I make Entity Framework understand my arbitrary expression in the way I want?

Comment: And the question is? Is it "How do I make Entity Framework interpret my arbitrary expression in the way I want?"?

Comment: Yeap, let me use your question to turn mine better =]

Comment: What's wrong with `type1s.Where(t1 => filter.Names.Contains(t1.Name))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply like this:

```
public Expression<Func<Type1, bool>> MyExpression(Type2 filter)
{
    return x => filter.Names.Contains(x.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public Expression<Func<Type1, bool>> MyExpression(Type2 filter)
{
    Expression<Func<Type1, bool>> expression =  t1 => filter.Names.Contains(t1.Name);
    return expression;
}
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862266/how-is-a-funct-implicitly-converted-to-expressionfunct) you can find good explanation why you can  convert a lambda expression to an expression tree.